# Sistema de ecuaciones con números complejos

Tags: numpy, sympy, números-complejos

Estoy haciendome un pequeño código para resolver un circuito y la parte de resolver el sistema de ecuaciones no lineales con números complejos me falla y cuando me da un resultado no es el correcto.
Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
    u6 = 1+0j
    s1 = 1+0j
   
    import sympy    
    #Variables simbolicas
    u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6 = sympy.symbols('u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6')
    vars=[u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6 ]
    

    #Sistema de ecuaciones no lineal
    F1 = sympy.re(zg*i6) + sympy.re(u6) - sympy.re(u5)
    F2 = sympy.re(i6) + sympy.re(u5*ytreq1) - sympy.re(i5)
    F3 = sympy.re(i5*ztreq1) + sympy.re(u5) - sympy.re(u4)
    F4 = sympy.re(i5) + sympy.re(u4*ypi) - sympy.re(i4)
    F5 = sympy.re(i4*zpi) + sympy.re(u4) - sympy.re(u3)
    F6 = sympy.re(i4) + sympy.re(2*ypi*u3) - sympy.re(i3)
    F7 = sympy.re(i3*zpi) + sympy.re(u3) - sympy.re(u2)
    F8 = sympy.re(i3) + sympy.re(ypi*u2) - sympy.re(i2)
    F9 = sympy.re(i2*ztreq1) + sympy.re(u2) - sympy.re(u1)
    F10 = sympy.re(i2) + sympy.re(u1*ytreq1) - sympy.re(i1)
    F11 = sympy.re(u1*i1.conjugate()) - sympy.re(s1)

    F12 = sympy.im(zg*i6) + sympy.im(u6) - sympy.im(u5)
    F13 = sympy.im(i6) + sympy.im(u5*ytreq1) - sympy.im(i5)
    F14 = sympy.im(i5*ztreq1) + sympy.im(u5) - sympy.im(u4)
    F15 = sympy.im(i5) + sympy.im(u4*ypi) - sympy.im(i4)
    F16 = sympy.im(i4*zpi) + sympy.im(u4) - sympy.im(u3)
    F17 = sympy.im(i4) + sympy.im(2*ypi*u3) - sympy.im(i3)
    F18 = sympy.im(i3*zpi) + sympy.im(u3) - sympy.im(u2)
    F19 = sympy.im(i3) + sympy.im(ypi*u2) - sympy.im(i2)
    F20 = sympy.im(i2*ztreq1) + sympy.im(u2) - sympy.im(u1)
    F21 = sympy.im(i2) + sympy.im(u1*ytreq1) - sympy.im(i1)
    F22 = sympy.im(u1*i1.conjugate()) - sympy.im(s1)
    system = [F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22]

    #Resolucion del sistema
    z = sympy.solve(system,vars)  #me devuelve una lista gigantesca formada por un diccionario
    return z
```

u6, s6, todas las z's e y's son valores complejos y conocidos.
¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal o no estoy teniendo en cuenta? Estoy bastante desesperada porque he probado con todo (sympy, spicy, numpy) y no consigo resolver el sistema ni obtener la solución correcta.
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tú código no es correcto o está mal copiado, tienes un `return` pero no tienes ninguna función definida

Comment: He copiado sólo la parte de la función que falla. La función acaba y debería devolver z, que son los valores que estoy intentando conseguir.

Comment: vale... Yo solo intentaba ayudarte...

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Esto te ayudará a hacer buenas preguntas, que facilitaran el trabajo a las personas que solidariamente quieren ayudarte. Preguntas que tienen el código a medio hacer, faltan variables que no están definidas, y hablan de cosas incroncretas como "con números complejos me falla" o "cuando me da un resultado no es correcto". ¿Qué fallo lanza con números complejos? ¿Qué resultado te da, y cuál sería el resultado correcto?

Comment: Todo lo anterior, sirve para ponerselo lo más fácil posible a una persona, que de forma gratuita quiere ayudarte y que no puede saber nada más sobre tu problema, que lo que tú escribas. Sin duda estos consejos que te he dado harán que tus preguntas reciban gran cantidad de ayuda por parte de la comunidad, en vez de caer en el olvido o ser cerradas.